# I need a delegate class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem that sounds like a delegation problem. I have a code like the following:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self,onEvent1="", onEvent2=""):
        self.OnEvent1=onEvent1
        self.OnEvent1=onEvent2

    def aLoop(self):
        ...
        #in case of event1
        self.OnEvent1()
        ...
        #in case of event2
        self.OnEvent2()


EventType=0

def MyBar1():
    print("Event Type1")
    EventType=1

def MyBar2():
    print("Event Type2")
    EventType=2

myFoo=foo(MyBar1,MyBar2)

while True:
    myFoo.aLoop()
    if (EventType==1):
        print ("EventType is 1")
        EventType=0
    elif (EventType==2):
        print ("EventType is 2")
        EventType=0
```

I can see the message of the `print()` inside the callback functions but not the `print()` of the messages in the while loop.
The variable `EventType` doesn't change its value.

What I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EventType` variables in `MyBar1` and `MyBar2` are *local variables*. Any variable you bind to is a local, unless explicitly configured otherwise; assignments, function parameters, a function or class definition and names you `import` are all ways to bind a name.

You need to use a `global` statement to change this:

```
def MyBar1():
    global EventType
    print("Event Type1")
    EventType=1

def MyBar2():
    global EventType
    print("Event Type2")
    EventType=2
```

Note that there is little point in giving your event arguments an empty string as default argument:

```
def __init__(self,onEvent1="", onEvent2=""):
```

If they are optional, set them to `None` and test for that:

```
def __init__(self, onEvent1=None, onEvent2=None):
    self.OnEvent1 = onEvent1
    self.OnEvent2 = onEvent2

def aLoop(self):
    ...
    #in case of event1
    if self.OnEvent1 is not None:
        self.OnEvent1()
    ...
    #in case of event2
    if self.OnEvent2 is not None:
        self.OnEvent2()
```

Comment: Tanks for the help, even in passing arguments.
I'm new in python programming, I normally write program in c and Vb.net.

Answer (score 1):

```
EventType=0

def MyBar1():
    global EventType
    print("Event Type1")
    EventType=1

def MyBar2():
    global EventType
    print("Event Type2")
    EventType=2
```

The problem is, you need to modify a *global* variable, but you're creating a local one instead. You can still *access* the global variable without using `global variable`. You need this to *modify* it.